# How To Get An Array Of MVC Partial View with Jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

I want to call a method in my controller via ajax with jQuery, and analyse the response in the `success`callback. But I want to send a array of partialview to this response, like in the following example:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/Admin/Design/ChangeQuestionType',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { 
        viewname: viewname,
        questionid: questionid, 
        questiontypeid:questiontypeid, 
        pageid: pageid 
    },
    success: function (response) {
        jQuery.each(response, function (i) {
            console.log(response);
            $('.questionvalidation').html(response[i])
        });
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
         alert(xhr.status);
         console.log(xhr.responseText);
         alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

and controller is :

```
public ActionResult ChangeQuestionType(string viewname, int questionid, int questiontypeid, int pageid) 
{
    var viewbody = PartialView(viewname);
    var viewtitle = PartialView("Title");
    List<ActionResult> responselist = new List<ActionResult>();
    responselist.Add(viewbody);
    responselist.Add(viewtitle);
    return Json(responselist, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

When the code is executed `console.log()` outputs :

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why you're returning JSON here? Just return the view as HTML if that's what you need.

Comment: is xml response expected by AJAX

Comment: dataType:"xml/json", whatever is expected

Comment: How Can i Return This as html?